# EasyAPNS not registering device to database for app thats now in production

Tags: iphone, device, apple-push-notifications, registering

I'm using easyapns to handle the Push Notifications for my app. Devices registered fine to the database while in development mode. When the app was run on the iphone, the iphone's details like deviceid etc. would register without error. I recently got my app approved on the app store, and now any new device will no register!

I've tried updating the production certificate (which I've done several times now) and still the same situation.

Looked everywhere for an answer and I've spent hours now trying to find a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You should be more specific.  What exactly fails? Do you get the prompt in your device to allow push notifications? Does the error delegate gets called?

Comment: The registration of the device that's opening the app fails. Basically when the user opens the app, it registers the user's device by sending details like the deviceid etc. to a mySQL database via php. Yep the user gets the prompt on the device to ask them if they want to allow push notifications. The strange thing is, everything works fine in development mode, and even ad-hoc... ie. the device registers fine. Hope this gives you more info, and thanks heaps for your help!

Comment: I'm beginning to suspect that my app isn't loading the 'appdelegate' (which the device registration code recides). Do you think that's the case?? It loads fine in development mode and even ad-hoc; however it doesn't seem to be loading at all now that it's on the app store. I dont know.. It's got my stumped!

Comment: I'm still not sure I understand what doesn't work. First of all, ad-hoc is identical to production (both use the production certificate and receive APNS sent to the production server). Now, in production env, does you app get the device token? Is `application:didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:` called or is `application:didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError:` called?

Comment: Thanks heaps for your reply; I just found out what the problem was... The server that did the registrations had a web publishing rule that was configured to block high-bit characters; so some devices successfully registered (the ones that did not have high-bit characters in their device name), while others didn't (the ones that HAD high-bit characters). So all I did was removed that rule and it now works fine... woohoo!!! Thanks heaps again for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just found out what the problem was... The server that did the registrations had a web publishing rule that was configured to block high-bit characters; so some devices successfully registered (the ones that did not have high-bit characters in their device name), while others didn't (the ones that HAD high-bit characters). So all I did was removed that rule and it now works fine.

Comment: I am also getting the error of not registering some devices to apns in production mode . How you solve this problem?